# Bitbucket server. REST API. How to enable "Transcode diffs" feature of the repository?

Tags: git, rest, server, bitbucket, transcoding

Does anybody know how to enable "Transcode diffs" feature in repo settings -> Repository details(checkbox named "git-enable-transcoding") in local Bitbucket server(stash) via REST API?

That's fine to create branch, clone & push changes, even make some settings changes via REST API, such as: permissions, branch model, etc., but...not this.
I've tried put something like

```
{'name': repository_slug, 'forkable': 'true', 'git-enable-transcoding': 'true'}
```

to

> http://{bitbucket_server}/rest/api/latest/projects/{project_key}/repos/{repository_slug}

and another tries without success( No luck at the Bitbucket forums too.
Please help, thanks in advance!

[image]